# Django: django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'book' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: python, django, web

I am working on CS50 Django tutorial. I am not able to open one of the pages and it shows the following error.

> Reverse for 'book' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s)
> tried: ['flights/(?P<flight_id>[0-9]+)/book$']

Here is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name="index"),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('<int:flight_id>', views.flight, name="flight"),
path('<int:flight_id>/book', views.book, name="book")
```

]

Here is my views.py related code

```
def book(request, flight_id):
if request.method == "post":
    flight = Flight.objects.get(pk=flight_id)
    passenger = Passenger.objects.get(pk=int(request.POST["passenger"]))
    passenger.flights.add(flight)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("flight", args=(flight_id,)))
```

I have used it in an html page

```
<form action="{% url 'book' flight.id %}" method="post"></form>
    {% csrf_token %}
```

I'd like to know what's the problem, I have checked some related problem but none of them are helpful

Comment: What view is rendering this template?

Comment: `flight.id` is null/empty.

Comment: can you share your full template and view  related to this issue ?